# Update program version google play market

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

we posted the program on the google play market. Now you need to almost completely change the design and add a lot of new functionality. The question is, if we write this program again (cleanly), keeping the package name and signing it with the same key, will Google accept it when we update, or do we need to edit this version and rewrite it? There are so many changes that it is easier to rewrite everything, including the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes google will accept it, google does not care about logic or functionality.
You have to make sure that you respect the [Developpers Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/) and also you have to republish the application with the same account that you used the first time otherwise there will be a conflict of package names